# Explanation of height behavior

Tags: css

Consider the following code:

```
<div id="outer" style="height:250px;background:red">
line
  <div id="med" style="height:auto;background:#000" >
     line1
          <div id="inner" style="height:100%;background:blue">
              line2<br/>    
              line3<br/>    
              line4<br/>   
              line5          
          </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script>
alert($("#outer").height());
alert($("#med").height());
alert($("#inner").height());
</script>
```

The results of the above alerts are:250, 100, 80. I 'd  expect 250, 100, 100 since div inner would have the med div's height because of height:100%. What is wrong in my syllogism?

Thank you

Comment: The inner div's height is as close to 100% as it can get, but the text "line1" is taking up space that would otherwise be available to the inner div. Hence, the 80px out of 100.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner div's height is as close to 100% as it can get, but the text "line1" is taking up space that would otherwise be available to the inner div. Hence, the 80px out of 100

Answer (score 1):

j08691 is correct, because of the text "line1" inside of `#med`, `#inner` can't occupy the full height.